# Interpreting from C language to MIPS

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I would like to create a MIPS program.
Here is my C code shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, row;

    printf("\nEnter a random row\n");
    scanf("%d", &row);

    for (i=1; i <= row; i++)
    {
        for (j=1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Then the code shown below is how I translate from C to MIPS:

```
    .data
word:   .asciiz "Please enter a random row: \n"
    .text
    .globl main

main:   
    la $a0, word        # load word
    li $v0, 4           # print integer
    syscall

    addi $s0, $s0, -1    # for accommodating loop condition
    lw $s1, i           # set i = 1
    lw $s2, j           # set j = 1
    lw $s3, row     # load row


loop1:
    blt $s0, $s1, exit  # for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
    addi $s1, $s1, 1     # i++
    li $s2, 1           # resets j to 1 after every iteration of for  loop
    move $a0, $t0        # move register to be printed into argument register $a0
    j loop2            # executing the nested for loop


loop2:
    blt $s1, $s2, loop1 # for(i = 0; i < j; i++)
    li  $v0, 1          # read_double => scanf("%d")
    move $a0, $t0        # move register to be printed into argument register $a0
    syscall
    j loop2


   li $v0, 10           # loading exit code
   syscall             # execute exit
```

In the beginning, although I did create the expected outcome, which is to ask user to insert the input random number, there is an upcoming issue which is the loop did not go through the whole program successfully. I was stuck in the loop 1.

Comment: If this is not a homework assignment please use a compiler to turn C code into assembler.

Comment: There are multiple bugs and most of them you should find when using debugger to single step over your code, for example your logic around `i` and `for` termination by `(i < row)` is not correct, etc... Did you even try to debug it? Seems like not.

Comment: `addi $s0, $s0, -1` <-- here you're making assumptions about `$s0`'s initial value. Also, the code you've posted doesn't even assemble because you've left out the declarations of `i`, `j` and `row`, and you have multiple comments with line breaks in them.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thx for noticing that, unfortunately this is my assignment project.

Comment: If you want real help and not just the community doing your assignment for you I suggest you try to debug it your self and if this does not work for you, come back with more a more specific question;) hint: http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/Help/Help_4_1/MarsHelpIntro.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect in a  few places, and comments are also wrong, which is probally a large part of the confusion.

Issues I see (hopefully not missing any):

```
main:   
    la $a0, word        # load word
    li $v0, 4           # print integer
```

- This is print string not  so the comment is wrong.
- Perhaps also because of that you don't read the integer that would correspond to the C scanf("%d", &row); line, so need add:

  ```
  li $v0, 5
  syscall
  move $s3, $v0
  ```

Next:

```
addi $s0, $s0, -1    # for accommodating loop condition
lw $s1, i           # set i = 1
lw $s2, j           # set j = 1
lw $s3, row     # load row
```

- not sure what s0 is for as you have variables for I, j and row
- you want to allocate a register for I and j and row, so don't need to load I or j into it (you don't have labels for them anyway) so the should real be something like:

  ```
  li $s1, 1           # set i = 1 
  li $s2, 1           # set j = 1
  ```

  - s3 (row) will need be loaded as part of the scanf addition

Next:

```
loop1:
    blt $s0, $s1, exit  # for(i = 0; i < row; i++)

    addi $s1, $s1, 1     # i++
```

- blt $s0, $s1, exit has wrong comment, has no exit label, need to compare I(s1) and row(s3) not s0.
- addi $s1, $s1, 1 should be after the loop 2 has completed as I is used in loop2 aos if incremented here will be wrong for the next loop.
- change to:

  ```
  loop1:
      blt $s3, $s1, exit_loop1  # for(i = 1; i <= row; i++)
  ```

Next:

```
move $a0, $t0        # move register to be printed into argument register $a0
j loop2            # executing the nested for loop - this does nothing as next instruction is loop2
```

- t0 is not set to anything and a0 is not being used here, so seems pointless
- j loop2 is jumping to next instruction, so not needed

Next:

```
loop2:
    blt $s1, $s2, loop1 # for(i = 0; i < j; i++)
```

- comment is wrong should be (j=1; j <= i; j++)
- need to print a newline and increment I from loop1 at end of loop2, so need to jump to an intermediate step before going back to loop1

Next:

```
li  $v0, 1          # read_double => scanf("%d")
move $a0, $t0        # move register to be printed into argument register $a0
syscall
```

- wrong comment for li - its print int
- you need to also increment j after the print

next:

- you don't print the newline after the end of loop2

So with all those changes I get:

```
  .data
word:   .asciiz "Please enter a random row: \n"
newline: .asciiz "\n" # added
  .text
  .globl main

main:   
  la $a0, word        # load word
  li $v0, 4           # print prompt
  syscall

  # read integer scanf(%d), save to s3
  li $v0, 5
  syscall
  move $s3, $v0

  li $s1, 1           # set i = 1 for loop 1
loop1:
  blt $s3, $s1, exit_loop1  # for(i = 1; i <= row; i++)

  # set up loop2 stuff
  li $s2, 1           # resets j to 1 after every iteration of for  loop

loop2:
  blt $s1, $s2, exit_loop2 

  li  $v0, 1          # print int j
  move $a0, $s2   
  syscall

  # increment j
  addi $s2, $s2, 1 

  j loop2

exit_loop2:
  # printf("\n");
  la $a0, newline        # load newline string
  li $v0, 4         
  syscall

  # increment loop1 i
  addi $s1, $s1, 1     # i++

  j loop1

exit_loop1:
  li $v0, 10           # loading exit code
  syscall             # execute exit
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to do his assignment for him? I mean super nice that you invested your time and pointed out all of his mistakes and explained it to him, yet posting the resulting code is kind of pointless. Additionally, this question lacks universality and is of no help to other users. No offense though, neither to you nor the questioner....